# JSONObject write to temp file

Tags: android, json, persistence

I am currently working on Android platform and developing small application. In my application I need one temporary file which contains my all JSON objects. I want to create new temp file and access to that temp file. What is the proper way to create file and storing data in it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to create hashmap arraylist to store ur all json objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have the data persist across application launches, so that you can retain data even if the application is killed, then You probably don't want to keep it in a file, and you will want to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Then, just store whatever JSON string you want to keep as a String.

If you just need the JSON information to be stored for that use only, Keep the objects in some sort of Array or List data structure.